# How to add data dynamically in data.json file in ReactJs like in my json file there is key-1 I have to add key-2 dynamically using add button?

Tags: reactjs

[this is image of my data.json file I have to add data in this dynamicall using reactjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdXET.png)

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can not write files in reactjs, As you must have known Reactjs runs on the browsers so there is no file system to do so.

You can write the file with help of Nodejs, Which provides the file system
For more details check this link out.
https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-fs-module

If you want to write to a file, you will have to send an API request from your front-end to a server and have that server write to the file system.